# iOS Safari memory leak when loading/unloading HTML5 <video>

Tags: ipad, ios, html, safari, html5-video

I've developed an iPad app with several UIWebViews that takes the following HTML and JavaScript. Since the iPad can only play one video at a time, I don't load the video until the particular web view is focused.

This is done by calling the *stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString* method on the UIWebView, sending in a call to the JS method *getFocus()*. Similarly, when the web view is no longer needed I call lostFocus() to unload the video. This enables another UIWebView to play another video.

So far, so good. Everything works perfectly. Except for one thing: **This causes a memory leak.** Whenever viewing

I've tried reloading the UIWebView (instead of unloading the video with JS), that didn't work. I've also tried a zillion of different JavaScript variations,  tag variations et cetera.

```
<div id="videoDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var movieDiv = document.getElementById('videoDiv'),
        movieHtml = '<video id="video" src="../Documents/<%= VideoFileName %>" width="768" height="911"></video>';

    var gotFocus = function () {
        movieDiv.innerHTML = movieHtml;
        var movie = document.getElementById('video');
        movie.play();
        movie.addEventListener('pause', function () {
            movie.currentTime = 0;
            movie.play();
        }, false);
    };
    var lostFocus = function () {
        movieDiv.innerHTML = '';
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I finally solved this! The solution was to empty the src and "load" a non-existing video. This causes no memory leak. Have a look:

```
<div id="videoDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var movieDiv = document.getElementById('videoDiv'),
        movieHtml = '<video id="video" src="" width="768" height="911"></video>';

    movieDiv.innerHTML = movieHtml;
    var movie = document.getElementById('video');

    var gotFocus = function () {
        movie.src = '../Documents/<%= VideoFileName %>';
        movie.load();
        movie.play();
        movie.addEventListener('pause', function () {
            movie.currentTime = 0;
            movie.play();
        }, false);
    };
    var lostFocus = function () {
        movie.src = '';
        movie.load(); // This line may be removed, see comments
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I had the EXACT same issue, the memory leak was bad, chrome doesn't like giving up resources. Browsers really dont like being treated as Stateless applications. Thank you for this discovery and answering your own question. +1

Comment: Simple and effective.  Worth noting, I don't see any difference in my testing between just setting the src='' and setting src then calling .load().  So you can probably lop that line off.

Comment: This seems to work for <audio> tags as well (and no need to call.load() either - not that I know if this even applies to <audio>, but still)

Comment: I have an app that was fine in iOS6 but stopped playing videos after a while in iO7. Using this trick has fixed it!

Comment: This seemed to work for me on desktop chrome also!

For those who want to see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/GhS2Z/3/

You can see the tab in task manager increase in memory when the line is commented out.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!
This solved a number of weird bugs I was having in Chrome (and only Chrome).

Comment: In 2020 Matt's link keeps leaking memory when clicking on the link no matter whether the line is commented out or not (Chrome).