# iOS app freezes, not crashing when loading video in webview

Tags: ios, html, video, safari

I have an iPad app developed using a 3rd party tool called OpenPlug which converts AS3 to C++ and from there on exports to iOS. (Just wanted to note this is not a "native" app using Obj-C in XCode written by me, I wrote AS3)

Now I have this iPad application which displays pictures and video in a slideshow. For the video I'm using a WebView which loads a HTML page where I change the src property of the video object to the location of the video file which was downloaded to my application storage. This is working fine except that the application freezes when it is running for a few hours (3-6).

I searched for this problem and tried the solution in [iOS Safari memory leak when loading/unloading HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170398/ios-safari-memory-leak-when-loading-unloading-html5-video) but that does not seem to change anything for me.

Since the application freezes (right before the HTML page needs to load a video) and does not crash what does that mean? Do I need to destroy the video object? First I was creating a new WebView for each video but now I'm reusing the webview and just changing the src property but that also does not help me.

Can anyone shed some light on this? OpenPlug has discontinued it service and does not offer any support anymore but nevertheless I think it is more of a webview/video problem on iPad (?)

Important to note: The application is freezing but my iPad is not. The application does not generate a crash report and does not execute any code anymore (also no traces). When I push the Home button on my iPad and press the app icon then the application is restarted.

Here is the code of my HTML page which is refreshed every time a new video needs to start (webview.location = ...)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function videoEndedHandler(){
                var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
                video.src = "";
                video.load();
                window.location.hash = "ended";
            }

            function videoErrorHandler(){
                window.location.hash = "error";
                var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
                video.src = "";
                video.load();
            }

                                    var loop;
                                    function setup(){
                                        var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
                                        video.addEventListener("error", videoErrorHandler,false);
                                        video.addEventListener("ended", videoEndedHandler,false);
                                        video.load();
                                        video.play();
                                        startHashLoop();
                                    }

                                    function startHashLoop(){
                                        if(window.location.hash == "#touched"){
                                            setAsPaused();
                                        }

                                        if(window.location.hash == "#paused"){
                                            //check image
                                            testImage("shouldResume.png?nocache=" + Math.random());
                                        }


                                        if(window.location.hash == "#resume"){
                                            var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
                                            video.play();
                                        }

                                        loop = setTimeout(hashLoop,500);
                                    }

                                    function testImage(url) {
                                        var img = new Image;
                                        img.addEventListener("load",isGood);
                                        img.addEventListener("error",isBad);

                                        img.src = url;
                                    }

                                    function isGood() {
                                        window.location.hash = "resume";
                                    }

                                    function isBad() {
                                        //alert("Image does not exist");
                                    }


                                    function hashLoop(){
                                        startHashLoop();
                                    }

                                    function setAsTouched(){
                                        window.location.hash = "touched";
                                    }

                                    function setAsPaused(){
                                        var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
                                        video.pause();
                                        window.location.hash = "paused";
                                    }
                                    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="setup();" style="background-color:#000000;">
    <a href="javascript:setAsTouched()" style="top:0;left:0;position:absolute;z-index:1;color:#FF0000;border:0px solid red;width:100%;height:100%;display:block;"></a>
        <video id="videoPlayer" style="top:0;left:0;position:absolute;" width="100%" height="100%" preload="auto" src="##VIDEO_URL##" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline />

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So in summary "My app freezes."  Show code or no one can help you.

Comment: Code of the HTML page was added

Comment: I also wonder why do apps freeze instead of crash? Any idea what the difference is?

Comment: Can anyone please help me? I have more info: The video freezes even though there is plenty of memory available so it's not a memory issue but for some reason a video freezes after my app is running for about 8 to 9 hours. This video was played before so I have no clue what it can be, anyone?

Comment: Please show your code that is loading this webpage.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you'd post your entire code, but I think it's freezing because you're loading a video from web in your main thread, which is also responsible for redrawing UI. By loading a large video inside your thread, your UI freezes as well.

I would recommend moving the code that does video loading into a separate thread (use blocks if you're on iOS5).

Comment: The problem is that I'm using OpenPlug, so I can not show any relevant  iOS code because I'm using intermediate code which gets compiled to iOS using C.