# iOS7 inAppBrowser displaying black boxes on PDFs

Tags: angularjs, pdf, cordova, ios7, inappbrowser

Having very inconsistent results in viewing PDFs on the iPad Air (ios 7.1.1). Memory consumption and CPU usage doesn't seem to be an issue. Getting black boxes and sometimes app crashes when viewing PDFs. Also it doesn't happen on the iOS simulator, but only the actual iPad.

Heres some screen shots.

[image]

[image]

This is how I'm opening the PDFs (using angular):

```
$scope.openPDF = function(pdfName) {
    var ref = window.open('img/pdfs/' + pdfName + '.pdf', '_blank', 'location=no');
};
```

Also, it seems like others are experiencing this problem.
https://discussions.apple.com/message/24129741#24129741
https://discussions.apple.com/message/23480067#23480067

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: All PDFs are in sRGB color mode as well.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** **This is still an issue. inAppBrowser does not fully garbage collect memory on PDFs**

Apparently this is related to an [HTML5 Video memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170398/ios-safari-memory-leak-when-loading-unloading-html5-video) bug.

inAppBrowser does not do garbage collection properly if an video tag exists on the page. Ended up removing the tags and everything seems to be working properly.

I also ended up using an [inAppBrowser Extension](https://github.com/cemerson/cordova-inappbrowser-ce) plugin for some of the extra options, it seems like [all the options from the official plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md#windowopen) are still supported which is nice.

I initially [filed a ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6903) and closed it.

[This is the thread](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/memory-leak/2823) where the HTML5 Video tag leak is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

From my research I cam to the same conclusion as @ChristopherMarshell that it is to do with a [HTML5 video tag memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170398/ios-safari-memory-leak-when-loading-unloading-html5-video?lq=1). Instead of using inAppBrowser to do the PDF document you could use Google docs, similar to:

`window.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.com/test.pdf&embedded=true', '_blank', 'location=yes');`

This opens the PDF in Google docs and you shouldn't get any black boxes :)